# How to set required field in contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a list of multiple checkboxes in the form. The user can check all the checkboxes but at least one is required. Without selecting at least one, checkbox they should not be able to submit the form. how to make it in contact form 7?
I have added the script which is not working.

 Here is my script

$(document).ready(function () {
   `$('#checkBtn').click(function() {`

checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

```
 if(!checked) {
    alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
    return false;
  }

});
```

});

Comment: Please show us your script

Comment: @HarshMehta added that above script but still it's not taking that script.

Answer (score 1):

In this only write star(*) after checkbox element in the plugin form

```
 [checkbox* checkbox "test 1" "test 2"]

 [submit "Send"]
```

Comment: i am adding separate checkbox like [checkbox checkbox-123 "10"]  [checkbox checkbox-124 "11"]. so here atleast they sholud select any one.

Comment: This is also work. add star(*) you want to require field.

Comment: ya, it will work. but here the user can select any one and 2 or more if they want. i have the list of 7 separate checkboxes. if we add the star(*) then the user should select all the checkboxes.  in that 7 checkboxes, the user can select any one or two or more. it's up to the user. but here I need at least they should select any one checkbox.

Comment: okay. I added above script but it's not taking in the contact form 7. in HTML form that script is working fine.

Comment: i create just demo in HTML. and this is all place working

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly work.
On this set your code

```js
$('#fm_submit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ck_box = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    
    // return in firefox or chrome console 
    // the number of checkbox checked
    console.log(ck_box); 

    if(ck_box < 1){
      alert('Select any one box');
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name = "frmTest[]" id="fm_submit">
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" >
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="true" >
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <input type="submit" id="fm_submit" name="fm_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: The above script I added in contact form 7 plugin inside the additional setting tab. it's not taking the script. exactly where can I add that script in contact form 7?

Comment: So "$('#fm_submit').submit(function(e){" in 'click' place of submit "$('#fm_submit').click(function(e){"

Comment: The script is not taking in contact form 7. I tried in adding an additional setting tab and below that form in form tab in contact form 7. both the places are not taking that script.

Comment: please check your js connection.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the code from above on the bottom of the form instead of the Additional Settings

```
$('#fm_submit').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var ck_box = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
// return in firefox or chrome console the number of checkbox checked enter code here
console.log(ck_box); 
if(ck_box < 1){ alert('Select any one box'); } 
});
```

Comment: The code does not get executed in the additional settings. It needs to be inserted at the bottom of the form section.